# How to get the values from webservice in android

Tags: android, json

I wrote a web service in asp.net and called it in my android application using a **JSON webservice**. This is my code to call the web service from android

```
httpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
JSONArray jsonArray=jobj.getJSONArray("d");
result=(String) jobj.getString("d")
```

I need to get each value from the result. How is it possible?
My web service result is:
`{"d":"{\"Password\":33,\"Userid\":\"343\",\"Username\":fgfg}"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
resultPassword = jsonArray.getString("Password");
```

That should work. Obviously change "Password" for each ID of the data you want to get.

Comment: but on this line   JSONArray jsonArray=jobj.getJSONArray("d"); i got an error. the error is "org.json.JSONException: Value {"Password":sas,"Userid":"sas","Username":asas} at d of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 1):

Just remove below line

```
JSONArray jsonArray=jobj.getJSONArray("d");
```

because you don't ve any `JSONArray` in your response then d is the only object then remaining all values are in string because all in double cotes("")...

First of all,form your json like below:

```
{"d":{\"Password\":33,\"Userid\":\"343\",\"Username\":fgfg}}
```

So,that you can get,

```
JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
JSONObject jsonObj=jobj.getJSONObject("d");
```

now you can get the value for Username like:

```
String Username = jsonObj.getString("Username");
```

Similarly you can get the other values also..

Comment: then how will i get the values from "result"

Comment: in the line JSONObject jsonObj=jobj.getJSONObject("d"); i got the "org.json.JSONException: Value {"Password":33,"Userid":"343","Username":fgfg} at d of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" error

Comment: how do i form the json like this {"d":{\"Password\":33,\"Userid\":\"343\",\"Username\":fgfg}}. i am new to android thats why i asked...! please help